# Automatically update Docker containers using webhooks

Tags: deployment, docker, docker-registry

I have created a Github repo and a Docker repo. Both work together very well: when I push a new version of Dockerfile to Github, a new image is automatically built inside the Docker repo.

Now, I'd like to have my running containers automatically updated when the base-image is (re)built.

How can I achieve it using Docker repos webhooks?

Comment: If there is an "easy" (as easy as this one) way to achieve the same thing without using webhooks, I'm also interested. :)

Comment: https://github.com/schickling/docker-hook

Answer (score 3):

The Century Link Labs team have developed a 2 new open source tools that can use web hooks to update running containers.

Their 1st app is **[Zodiac](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/zodiac)** that uses a "push" deployment model. Its a lightweight tool built on top of [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), for easy deployment and rollback of dockerized applications.  It maintains a history of all deployments that also allows you to rollback to a previous deployment.

- [Zodiac: Easy Container Deployment & Rollback](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/zodiac-easy-container-deployment-rollback/)
- [GitHub Project](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/zodiac)

Their 2nd app **[Watchtower](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower)** uses a "pull" deployment model.  This model allows Docker containers that reside behind a firewall to detect and more safely pull changes without exposing an external port.

Watchtower knows how to properly restart a set of linked containers. If an update is detected for one of the dependencies in a group of linked containers, Watchtower will stop and start all of the containers in the correct order so that the application comes back up correctly.

- [Watchtower: Automatic Updates for Docker Containers](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/watchtower-automatic-updates-for-docker-containers/)
- [GitHub Project](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower)

I have no affiliation with Century Link Labs.

Another simpler app you might want to have a look at is **[Docker Puller](https://github.com/glowdigitalmedia/docker-puller)**.

- [Automatically pull updated Docker images and restart containers with docker-puller](https://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/10/25/automatically-pull-updated-docker-images-and-restart-containers-with-docker-puller/)
- [Github Project](https://github.com/glowdigitalmedia/docker-puller)

Comment: You might also want to have  look at this discussion on [apply security updates from base images](http://serverfault.com/questions/611082/how-to-handle-security-updates-within-docker-containers)

Comment: Some of these links are now broken but GitHub projects remain

Comment: Broken links updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a more recent one [docker-image-puller](https://github.com/tuxity/docker-image-puller)

It's connected directly to your Docker's socket and use the Docker API to update your running containers which use the image you specify in the webhook. It's pretty simple, maybe more options can be added in the future

Answer (score -1):

I found this, but I haven't tried yet:

https://medium.com/@iaincollins/docker-swarm-automated-deployment-cb477767dfcf this is an article about use webhook to deploy container with docker hub.

Basically, it tells you could use kind of tool(check the link below), to handle webhook on your docker "machine".
https://github.com/iaincollins/docker-deploy-webhook

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think my answer would be helpful, I added more description.