# Security maintenance on cloud instances created with docker-machine?

Tags: security, docker, cloud, maintenance, docker-machine

After reading about [some people's issue with Docker hosts' time going out of sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551592/how-to-make-sure-dockers-time-syncs-with-that-of-the-host), I realized that my Docker host on Digital Ocean (created via docker-machine) may want ntp running on it, and that got me thinking about system updates to the Docker hosts in general.

There has already been a good discussion on [applying updates to the actual docker services](https://serverfault.com/questions/611082/how-to-handle-security-updates-within-docker-containers/) -- with general agreement that rebuilding images from updated base images is good solution -- but I haven't seen much focus on the Docker hosts themselves.

For those using Docker in a production environment, are you even bothering with docker-machine, or are you building and maintaining your Docker hosts with traditional tools like Chef/Puppet/etc?