# Patching a container's host/base OS without vendor support for app layer?

Tags: security, docker, windows-server-2016, containers

Scenario: Mature server application from vendor running inside a Windows container. Vendor's app is built (`Dockerfile`) and shipped to customer (to customer's container registry via `docker push ...`). No vendor software updates are expected in the near future.

Question: How does the customer's ops team patch the underlying OS without direct access to vendor's source or app? Is it possible to peel-off and swap the base OS layers for a new image that can we deployed (statelessly)?

Reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/611082/how-to-handle-security-updates-within-docker-containers/) doesn't seem positive.

Edit: This is a future scenario we’re planning for; not something from the past

Comment: You got an image as an app distribution method, instead of a `Dockerfile` that employs some non-docker app distribution method?

Comment: @kubanczyk clarified it’s a future scenario. Standard Docker commands where the IIS app binaries are copied over and system config is tweaked via powershell towards the end of the vendor’s Dockerfile